# How to fetch data in vueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

a column data is showing in array : ["1k","2k","3k"]
I used foreach to filter and the data type is showing string and it shows like this again: ["1k","2k","3k"]

1. If I convert this into an array then v-for loop does not show data.
2. photographers data is the API action state.
   Output: I want to print each value in dropdown from this array.
3. I am trying to do v-for on print.
4. I tried to do print as a computed function but no result.
5. If you want all code then I can print its too much logic that's why I have trimmed it which is required.

Thanks

code:

````
data() {
return {
 print: [],
  printPrice: [],
},
computed: {
getImageDetails(){ 
        this.photographersdata.forEach((details) => {
            if(details.id === parseInt(this.imageId)){
                this.print = details.print;
                this.printPrice = details.print_price;
            }
        })
    },```
````

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Hi, I have added the code in the initial problem.

Comment: I think print is an array you have to push the data into it.

Comment: if I push it then data does not show but console log shows like this
0: "[\"1k\",\"2k\",\"3k\"]"

Comment: console this.photographersdata and let me show the console image

Comment: `JSON.parse("[\"1k\",\"2k\",\"3k\"]")`

Comment: Basically vue is treating print as string instread of array. First convert it into array or object using json.parse(...)

Comment: One thing I noticed, it could be possible due to this. the datatype of the column of this value in mysql is varchar and data is storing like this: "[\"1k\",\"2k\",\"3k\]".  Is this could be the reason?

Comment: Yes it is the reason. You can use json_array https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://database.guide/json_array-create-a-json-array-from-a-list-of-values-in-mysql/%23:~:text%3DIn%2520MySQL%252C%2520you%2520can%2520use,i.e.%2520you%2520provide%2520no%2520arguments).&ved=2ahUKEwi44LO3oZP4AhWLRmwGHelkCg0QFnoECA0QBQ&usg=AOvVaw29ONttBxqI1wgphq1CAIex. Don't forget to parse it in your vue js application before using

Comment: Thank you guys. this is because of db value howevver, if I json.parse and assign it into array then it shows correctly.